# Level selection on dropdown

Tags: website-design, navigation, dropdown, radio-buttons, ordering

Designing a radio button interface for selecting how many sub-levels you would want to display for a website main menu dropdown.

The options are:

- OFF
- 1 level
- 2 levels

Considering that the default will be "2 levels" and the options will be vertically listed in one column.

Should the 2 come first as it is the default option, for example:

- 2
- 1
- OFF

OR

the reverse of this as it would display as a dropdown, for example:

- OFF
- 1
- 2

Current display is default option first:

[image]

Comment: Are you forced to do it with radio buttons or is a dropdown also possible?

Comment: Could you please upload an image or wireframe/mockup.

Comment: @iboothcreate is there a reason they need to be vertically listed?

Comment: @Michael - It is standard across our system to display these options as radio buttons.

Comment: @JeffH - unfortunately as a new user I can't upload images yet

Comment: @GotDibbs The current interface only has space for vertical listing.

Comment: @iboothcreate use the balsamiq mockup feature. Its a nice and intuitive tool that you should have access to.

Comment: @JeffH sorry can you point me in the right direction...

Comment: @iboothcreate it should be the icon next to image. I looks like a wireframes with a pencil.

Comment: @JeffH Balsamiq needs 10+ rep to be able to use, the same as posting images.

Comment: @JeffH image added

Comment: @iboothcreate I saw, Thanks! I have posted a answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would begin by having the default selection set to "OFF" and then use the:

> - OFF
> - 1
> - 2

This is pretty standard to have the more "beginner" options at the top and then as the list descends, give the user more "advanced" options.

Something I can foresee being a problem is the user actually knowing what this section **does**. A description or demo of what each selection does would be helpful.

Comment: This is for deciding how many levels they would like the dropdown to appear on the front end of their website, not for account navigation.

Comment: edited it now...

Comment: Using this way would you then consider having the default as "off"? To add a bit more context here for you. This option will only show when choosing a "Drop-down" template from the list, which is how we are trying to counteract users being unsure what the buttons are for, the text could be changed though as more of a CTA e.g "How many levels would you like to display?".

Comment: Yes, I would set the default as "Off". As far as the wording is concerned, would it be possible for you to show the user a demo of what "off" or "2 levels" would look like? I really believe that would be the most user friendly way to approach it without having to write a paragraph explaining what it means.

Comment: not currently unfortunately, working on it though

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly. The order should be Off > 1 > 2. As the number of level of navigation increase; the discover-ability and the usability of your navigation contents can greatly decrease. Accessibility can also become increasingly harder as the number of option levels and options increase as well.

Comment: Yeah I am kind of in the same mindset but when you consider 1 & 2 as "ON" options, I wouldn't expect to list the "OFF" option first in a vertical list. Also with the default being "2" would you expect this first?